# DOSBox screen capture to specific file

Tags: bash, dosbox, xdotool

I have a project where I am trying to 'stream' a DOS game, working in DOSBox on Ubuntu. The idea is to take screenshots of the screen, then upload these to a server. To take screenshots from DOSBox, I use xdotool to trigger the key combination "Ctrl+F5", which triggers a screen capture. The screenshot is then saved into the /capture folder, from which I can read the file.

The problem is that the screenshots are named progName_000.png, progName_001.png, ... I would prefer that a single file is overriden. Is it possible to achieve?

Currently I am using the horrendous bash code below:

```
WID=`xdotool search --limit 1 --name "DOSBox" 2>/dev/null`
while [ 1 ]; do
    fN=`ls ./DOSBox/capture/ | head -1`
    cp ./DOSBox/capture/$fN ./img.png
    rm ./DOSBox/capture/*

    xdotool key --window $WID Ctrl+F5
    sleep 0.10;
done
```

Every 100 ms, I read the capture file, take the first file that I encounter, copy it to ./img.png, and clear the capture folder, and take another screenshot. What is a better alternative?

*(P.S: The above code is simplified; normally I copy the captured images to more than one image; img0.png and img1.png, so that while one is being written on, the other can be read, like page flipping. Anyway.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by tampering with the compiled DOSBox binary directly. I could have edited the source and simply built the project, but where is the fun in that?

The binary file is in /usr/bin/dosbox. I opened `gdb` in a terminal as root and wrote

```
gdb -write -silent /usr/bin/dosbox
```

This is the solution for my DOSBox 0.74 binary, compiled for Ubuntu 14.04.

First, the screenshot filenames include a 3-digit number, such as 'whatevs_000.png'. It was likely that the filename was constructed as a string using the `sprintf` function call, using a format string that included either `%3d` or `%03d`. A lucky search with `objdump -s /usr/bin/dosbox | grep "\%03"` revealed that the string `"%s%c%s%03d%s"` was indeed stored at `0x5fa9c7`.

After setting a hardware access watchpoint with `awatch *0x5fa9c7`, I `run`ned the program in `gdb` (several `continue`s might be required). Once the DOSBox boots, I used Ctrl+F5 to take a screenshot and trap the program at the instruction in the sprintf function. After several `up`s, I was in the main program flow (address `0x4a9949`). `disass`ing upwards, I discovered a `for` loop that had standard library calls to achieve directory listing. I detected the entry point of the loop (using two `continue` statements in the loop, which I verified later by checking the source code), and replaced the for-loop termination statement (0x4a9854) with an unconditional jump to the end of the loop (0x4a9908) as below:

```
set write on

set *(unsigned char*)0x4a9854 = 0xeb     Short jump to 0x4a98d4
set *(unsigned char*)0x4a9855 = 0x7e

set *(unsigned char*)0x4a9856 = 0x90     Fill the remaining
set *(unsigned char*)0x4a9857 = 0x90     bytes of the previous
set *(unsigned char*)0x4a9858 = 0x90     instruction with NOPs
set *(unsigned char*)0x4a9859 = 0x90     because why not

set *(unsigned char*)0x4a98d4 = 0xeb     Short jump to 0x4a9908
set *(unsigned char*)0x4a98d5 = 0x32
```

(I make two short jumps to jump over a longer range because this is the only opcode I could remember by heart and I am too sleepy to Google the rest)

After this point, DOSBox always overrides `filename_000.png`, `filename` being the name of the binary being emulated.